# Uitabbarcontroller and uinavigationcontroller howto

Tags: iphone

general question here.
I have an iphone app that initially has a uitableviewcontroller (with search in order to query through a list of entities). In my case car information.

Upon selecting an entity, what i do now, is pushing the "genericcarinformation" view controller to the navigation controller. This is a uitableviewcontroller sincei display the information in cells. So far, its simple.

What i would like to do and this is what i am asking, is the following:
each entity of a car can contain other advanced information that do not belong in the generic view. This could be one or more views. So i would need another view (or views) to display this information. For example i need "carAdvancedInfo1" and "carAdvancedInfo2" view controllers.

One way to do this (and the way i have done it so far) is by displaying the generic car info and at the bottom of the view. So, i add two more cells which push the "carAdvancedInfo1" and "carAdvancedInfo2" view controllers on top of the "genericcarinformation" view controller.

Second way: Is it possible to use a uitabbarcontroller? For example, selecting a car cell in my top view would open a uitabbarcontroller that would contain 3 tabs: generic, advanced1 and advanced2. Can i do this while keeping the uinavigationcontroller to go back and forth?

I assume this is not possible to be done as it does not follow properly the design architecture of the iOS. Am i right? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Second way as you described is possible...I know 1 app..look at at&t app for iPhone ...you can download it but the log in is just for at&t users ..

I believe AT&T app is doing presenting modal view at the start... and the on the click of any of the cells or button... showing the clicked tabbar selected..